# React Concat Loop's index number in event.target.Name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-redux, concatenation

In React, I am using `onSubmit` to call function and then updating multiple states in the function. I have repeated Director Name fields in the form where user can click on + icon and add a new field. The fields are named as `"DirectorName1"`, `"DirectorName2"` and so on.

I am also saving total number of Directors in a different state value.

In function, I am looping through total number of Directors and then trying to access `DirectorName` field's value and concatenating the array index number in value.

Here is the code:

```js
let newIndex = '';

{[...Array(aboutDetails.companyDirectors)].map((elementInArray, index) => (
  newIndex = index + 1,
  console.log(event.target.directorName + index.value)
))}
```

But it shows the value as `NaN`. The main issue I am getting is I am unable to append index number dynamically in `event.target.directorName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issues

1. If the logic is an a `form` element's `onSubmit` handler and `directorName` is one of the form fields then you should be accessing `directorName.value` to get the field value.
2. The array `index` is also a number type, so `index.value` is
   undefined. You likely just want to reference `index`, or rather, the computed `newIndex` value.
3. The `Array.prototype.map` callback function is returning a [Comma Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) expression, so the result of the `console.log`, i.e. `undefined` is returned as the mapped array element value.
4. The array is being mapped to new values, but the returned mapped array isn't saved or referenced.

## Solution

```js
const directorNames = aboutDetails.companyDirectors
  .map((elementInArray, index) => {
    const newIndex = index + 1;
    const newDirectorName = event.target.directorName.value + String(newIndex);
    
    console.log({ newDirectorName });

    return newDirectorName; // <-- return mapped value!
  });
```

Comment: Thank you!

Issue is form fields name is dynamically generated with incremented number, like directorName1, directorName2, directorName3 and so on.

And i need to append index number with the event.target.directorName[index_here].value to get the field's value in a loop.